# Can't print all the numbers within a fibanocci series

Tags: java

I'm trying to print fibanocci series within some give range. I've found the problem in my code but, i can't fix it.

I have tried everything as per my knowledge

```
import java.util.*;

class Fiba {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int v1 = 0;
        int v2 = 1;
        Scanner gump = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter the term :");
        int term = gump.nextInt();
        int result;
        int result1;
        int v3;
        System.out.print(v1 + "," + v2);
        while (term > v2) {
            result = v1 + v2;

            result1 = result + v2;
            v1 = result;


            v2 = result1;

            if (v2 < term) {

                System.out.print("," + v1 + "," + v2);

            }


        }

    }
}
```

The problem is , when the loop runs v2 is assigned to a bigger value than the term. so, it refuses to show complete series.I need a solution to print the all numbers in the series.

Comment: can you show expected and actual output?

Comment: example: if i give term =10, i need it to print like 0,1,1,2,3,5,8 .But, it only prints till 5 only. The problem is v2 is assigned to 13 so ,it refuses to print 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more check and break loop when result1 > term

```
while (term > v2) {
            result = v1 + v2;

            result1 = result + v2;

           if(result1>term){
            System.out.println("," + result);
            break;
        }else{
            v2 = result1;
            v1 = result;
        }

            if (v2 < term) {

                System.out.print("," + v1 + "," + v2);

   }
```

This program print **0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89** if term is 100.

Comment: dude try term=10 , you will have the problem i have

Comment: @TroubleMaker try it now. It's not ellegant. I just correct you solution. Pls let me now if you find some bugs again. And i would recommend to solve this task with recursion.

Comment: @TroubleMaker Can you aprove my answer if it's helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that with each iteration, you actually calculate two steps in the Fibonacci series. so it will work only if the series has even number of items. You need to change the iteration to calculate one number at a time. 
an example solution would be

```
int v1 = 0;
int v2 = 1;
System.out.print(v1 + "," + v2);
while (term > v2) {
    int temp = v2;
    v2 += v1;
    if (v2 < term) {
        System.out.print("," + v2);
    }
    v1 = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to  calculate one fibanocci number at a time. an example solution would be

```
while (term > v2) {
            r = v1 + v2;

            r1 = result + v2;

           if(r1<term){
                v2 = r1;
                v1 = r;
            }else{
                break;
            }

            if (v2 < term) {

                System.out.print("," + v1 + "," + v2);

   }
```